# MacBook Pro Battery

Tags: mac

I have a MacBook Pro mid 2012 unibody and it does not charge the battery.
This Mac was used by one of my friends for two years with the batter still working and kept for one year without using it.
The battery is not detected.
What do I need to do disclosing buying a new battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the battery has deep discharged and it needs some time before it starts charging properly and even before it's shown as present...

Here are most of the answers about batteries, from Apple knowledge base:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1119

Comment: I thought so but it has been like this for a year now